# How this greatest common divisor (gcd) works in python

Tags: python

I have taken a piece of code from http://www.s-anand.net/euler.html, problem 5:

```
def gcd(a,b): 
    print a,b
    return b and gcd(b, a % b) or a

print gcd(10,20)
```

Giving output:

```
10 20

20 10

10 0

10
```

Why the last line prints only "a" not b.

Can you please explain how the return statement in above code works.

I am little bit confused with "and" and "or" operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
b and gcd(b, a % b) or a
```

was the old way of writing:

```
gcd(b, a % b) if b else a
```

Comment: Note that `a if b else c` was added to the language because of the frequent bugs resulting from misunderstanding/misusing `b and a or c`; If `a` is a false value, it will never be returned. `True and "" or "Oops"` is `"Oops"`, while `"" if True else "Oops"` is `""`.

Answer (score 6):

Python's `and` and `or` operators use a type of [short-circut evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) that is a little confusing at first.

If they were written as function, they would work sort-of like this, except that they don't even evaluate the right value unless they need to.

```
def and(left, right):
    if left:
        return right
    else:
        return left

def or(left, right):
    if left:
        return left
    else:
        return right
```

So the line `return b and gcd(b, a % b) or a` could be written more verbosely as:

```
if b:
    temp_1 = gcd(b, a % b)
else:
    temp_1 = False

if temp_1:
    return temp_1
else:
    return a
```

If you work out the logic, this is equivalent to the common method for finding a GCD. However, unless you're already familiar with Python this code will be hard to read, so you might want to avoid this style.

Answer (score 3):

Because 10 is the greatest common divisor in your case, e.g. result of gcd(10,20)

Your code(return b and gcd(...) or a) is the same as:

```
def gcd(a,b): 
    print a,b
    if b:
        return b      
    else:
        res = gcd(b, a % b)
        return res if res else a
```

Also note that there [gcd method in fractions module](http://docs.python.org/library/fractions.html?highlight=gcd#fractions.gcd):

```
from fractions import gcd
print gcd(10,20)
```

Comment: please refrain from using 'bcoz'.

Comment: @C-Ram but why? Is it so bad? Is there any rule about this? Could you give me a link to this?

Comment: I found a meta discussion close to the subject of spelling and grammar (close, but not quite it). [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25/should-users-edit-other-users-posts-to-correct-grammar-and-spelling-problems). in my opinion, answers in complete english, without text-speak look much nicer.

Comment: @C-Ram - thank you. Will take a look into it. I agree with you but to be honest i started to use 'bcoz, u' and etc. after a numerous of projects with USA and India people.